# SFCC: Is there a tool to analyse pipeline and controller usage?

Tags: salesforce-commerce-cloud

We have a quite big and old SFCC project, which started on Pipelines and should now finally be migrated to Controllers. For this we need to identify, which Pipelines are easy candidates for an initial migration.

We are doing it based in the following criteria:

- which other Pipelines are calling this pipeline
- how many `Pipeline.execute` calls are in existing controllers to this pipeline
- Is the pipeline using a custom hooking mechanism (identified on a certain include pipeline) - I guess it can be abstracted by "What other pipelines is this Pipeline calling"

Is there already something out there that does something close to this?

Comment: Jea, I also don't like Pipelines, but no reason to downvote this I would say ;) It might be a valid usecase to other projects too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case somebody else has this challenge, to get eventually rid of Pipelines in a legacy Project, you can use my node analyser script also:

https://github.com/Andreas-Schoenefeldt/SFCCAnalyser

after installation, start it with `npm run`